# Create list of index of array sorted from largest to smallest

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array `y_probability` which is 2 dimensional. It contains the probability that an instance belongs to each class. I would like to create a list of the indexes of the `y_probabiltiy` array ordered from largest to smallest on the first column. How can I do this?

Sample data:

```
y_probability = np.array([[0.3,0.7],[0.5,0.5] ,[0.2,0.8], [0.1,0.9]])
```

Desired output:

```
index = [2,1,3,4]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `argsort` on the first column (note the index in python is 0 based, so the result will be one less than what you expect), then reverse the result with `[::-1]` since `argsort` returns index that sorts array in ascending order:

```
y_probability[:,0].argsort()[::-1]
# array([1, 0, 2, 3])
```

Comment: np.argsort(y_probability,axis = 0)[:,0][::-1] also same result

Comment: Another (slower) option is `(-y_probablility[:,0]).argsort()` - negate instead of reversing